# Sync Data Without Replication

Tags: mysql

I have a database server I am using an old dump from to restore due to the need of older records that must be brought back. I also need to sync to this database the new entries from the current database server. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What are you using for PRIMARY KEYs?

Comment: They  vary per table

Comment: Are they unique for each table?

Comment: And do they have the same names in both databases?

Comment: No some are different. Really I only need to sync one large database

Answer (score 1):

First step - **take a backup** of both databases (and other files my.cnf &c.)

Second step - you have your mysqldump of your old database.

Third step - edit the old mysqldump file and change the line

CREATE DATABASE `old_database_name` (may have backticks around name - also I'm assuming that old_database_name is the same as the current_database_name).

to

CREATE DATABASE `staging` (or name of your choice, but not one that
already exists in the current server schemas - SHOW SCHEMAS; will show you this information.

Fourth step - Using the MySQL client (or MySQL Workbench), create an empty schema on the current database also called `staging` (CREATE SCHEMA staging;)

Fifth step - "restore" the staging database to the current server, using the instructions from [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/).

In this case, it will be

```
mysql -u root -p[root_password] staging < old_dumpfilename.sql
```

So, you now have the current and old databases on the current server, **BUT** in different schemas.

Sixth step - Your main worry now is how to resolve any conflicts of PRIMARY KEYs.

You can check this by running

```
SELECT staging.old_table_PK from staging.old_staging_table_name 
WHERE staging.old_table_PK 
IN (SELECT current.current_table_PK FROM current.curent_table_name);
```

You need to specify the schema name because you are running cross schema queries. The above query will give you any records in both tables which have the same PRIMARY KEY. It will be up to you to resolve any conflicts using your system's logic.

Perform this query for all tables in your current database.

Seventh step - If there are no conflicts, then perform

```
INSERT INTO current.current_table_name SELECT * from staging.staging_table_name;
```

This should get you most of the way there. There may be typos in my answer, since I didn't have suitable data to perform a large scale check - but you can do any necessary testing yourself.

**REMEMBER - BACKUP before you MESSUP!**

Comment: Wouldn't a proper ETL tool and according scripts the more suitable solution?

Comment: OK, well the OP didn't ask about those - I suppose they could be a consideration, but I didn't go into that since (from what I understood of the OP's question), this is some sort of one-off operation, so purchasing and/or learning to configure such a tool might be overkill.

Comment: Well, true. On the other hand, there is database change management likely tbd.

Comment: Be marvellous to work in such environments all the time - but (sing to the song's tune) "it ain't necessarily so...."